# Flutter http.get is not responding

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I used exactly same code from [Flutter Documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) to fetch data from internet.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  const Album({
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.title);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It should display data with text widget after getting data, but `http.get` is not returning and it just keeps showing CircularProgressIndicator like:

[image]

I'm using Windows 10, Flutter 3.7.0 stable channel, Dart 2.19.0, http 0.13.5 version. How to fix this?

Comment: Check dev tools in browser and see what happening in network

Comment: Your code is fine, check your network connectivity

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you haven't added the interne permissions in you android manifest

```
<manifest...
...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
....
/manifest>
```